# Can I run long tasks in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a Spring Boot application, which shows some data from MongoDB on an AngularJS page and allows the user to change it.

Now I need to create a mechanism, which allows me to

1. run a long (1-3 hours) Java method,
2. which produces some files and
3. observe its state via web (does it run, is it finished, did it crash?).

Can I implement this in scope of the Spring Boot application? If yes, what parts of Spring can I use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that it's **not good idea to embed batch processing into your service** exposing MongoDB data store.

I would create **separate batch application**. **[Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/htmlsingle/) would be natural choice** if you are using Spring stack. You would need to figure out how you want to host Spring Batch job and how you want to trigger and schedule it. **Spring Batch needs SQL storage for it's metadata**.

Status of the batch processing could be monitored by one other application with **[Spring Batch Admin module](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html) running on Servlet container**. If you point this application to SQL storage of Spring Batch job application, you get **monitoring of status via web UI out of the box**.

Of course it could run each app with Spring Boot.

If you don't want to handle this operational complexity it brings to host there three applications, yous still can **all three embed into one and it would work fine with Spring Boot**. You could even execute jobs with parameters manually or restart them via Spring Batch Admin configured to have access to Spring Batch Job beans.

You could also explore using MongoDb as storage for Spring Batch metadata. [E.g. this project may help](https://github.com/jbaruch/springbatch-over-mongodb). But such mechanism would need to be used by Spring Batch application and also by Spring Batch Admin module visualizing status of processing.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding SQL storage: Is a lightweight database such as H2, Derby or something similar enough for Spring Batch?

Comment: Yes, it is. although you probably want to avoid in memory DB. H2 or Derby with stored in file are 100% supported by Spring Batch.

Comment: BTW, I have created bunch of examples on Spring Batch framework for upcoming book I am working on. Examples are using Spring Boot mostly and H2 as storage for metadata: https://github.com/lkrnac/book-eiws-code-samples/tree/master/09-batch